# getting a weird blue color around a button only in chrome

Tags: html, css

attach is a screen shot,for some reason when clicking on the button the blue part appears.

[image]

this is the code I use for this buttons:

html:

```
<div style="display:table-cell;" class="btnRight">
    <span class="scrollUp" onclick="mobile_scrollUp();"></span>
    <div style="clear:both"></div> 
    <span class="scrollDown" onclick="mobile_scrollDown();"></span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.btnRight .scrollUp {
   width: 35px;
   height: 35px;
   background: url(../images/up-down-arrows.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
}

.btnRight .scrollUp {
   width: 35px;
   height: 35px;
   background: url(../images/up-down-arrows.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
}

.previews-status span {
   margin: 7px 0 0 0;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: You are setting them as background images so it is hard to tell what is wrong without the actual images.

Comment: where is your JS method?

Comment: Could you recreate this behaviour in jsFiddle, please? With your images if it's possible... So, we can inspect it in the Chrome inspection panel... thanks!

Comment: JSFIDDLE Please.....@eyal halperin

Answer (score 3):

input { outline:none; }  worked for me if your using < input type="button" >

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Internet Explorer?
IE adds a blue bordered around things for some stupid reason.
To get rid of it add this to you CSS:

```
body {
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Try @Adsy answer for chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Similar to @safinn answer, when using chrome sometimes buttons get strange outlines.

This eliminates it:

```
area {
    outline : none;
}
```

Comment: You should avoid `!important` at all costs. There are really specific situations where you could use it, and this is not one of them.